# sql table's count() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count names as total

TABLE 1 is

```
PROGRAM, PART,COLOR
```

TABLE 2 is

```
SERIAL,NAME
```

Query:

```
select program,table_1.part_customer,color, table_2.[serial],table_2.operator
from table_1 
inner join table_2 
on Table_1.[PART_customer]=table_2.[PART_customer_1]
```

**OUTPUT is shown below;**

```
PROGRAM     PART    COLOR     SERIAL    NAME              
-------     ----    -----      ----     -----
BMW          100    BLUE      1         STEVE
BMW          100    BLUE      1         STEVE
BMW          100    BLUE      1         STEVE
MERCEDES     200    SILVER    2         NEIL
MERCEDES     200    SILVER    2         NEIL
AUDI         300    GREEN     3         JOHN
AUDI         300    GREEN     3         JOHN  
MERCEDES     200    SILVER    2         NEIL
MERCEDES     200    SILVER    3         NEIL
BMW          100    BLUE      1         STEVE
BMW          100    BLUE      1         STEVE
GM           500    RED       5         MIKE
GM           500    RED       5         MIKE
GM           500    RED       5         MIKE
VOLKSWAGEN   400    BLACK     4         DAVID
VOLKSWAGEN   400    BLACK     4         DAVID
VOLKSWAGEN   400    BLACK     4         DAVID
VOLKSWAGEN   400    BLACK     4         DAVID
VOLKSWAGEN   400    BLACK     4         DAVID
```

**I would like to get an output as;**

```
PROGRAM     PART    COLOR     SERIAL    NAME      TOTAL          
-------     ----    -----      ----     -----     -----
BMW         100    BLUE       1        STEVE      5
MERCEDES    200    SILVER     2        NEIL       4
AUDI        300    GREEN      3        JOHN       2
GM          500    RED        5        MIKE       3
VOLKSWAGEN  400    BLACK      4        DAVID      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select program,table_1.part_customer,color, 
    table_2.[serial],table_2.operator, count(*) as total
from table_1 
inner join table_2 
on Table_1.[PART_customer]=table_2.[PART_customer_1]
group by program,table_1.part_customer,color, table_2.[serial],table_2.operator
```

You should really use table aliases for your tables, and use that alias for all the columns in the query because otherwise your SQL might break if someone adds a column with the same name in one of the tables in your query.

Comment: it does not work for the each name. Every time the same name  inserted, on that particular name is not accumulated for totals

Comment: @Chelsea Well, then you haven't described your problem correctly. This SQL works with given cases just fine, please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae57/1 vs http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae57/2